# Inspect Model relations

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I am trying to inspect my `Eloquent` models to find out their relations to other Models. The problem is that relations are simply defined as a single method and no central index of relations exists:

```
public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Post');
}
```

In order to inspect all relations I need to extract the list of methods, take out the ones inherited from `Eloquent`, execute each single one and check the return type:

```
$all = get_class_methods($model);
$inherited = get_class_methods('Eloquent');
$unique = array_diff($all, $inherited);

foreach($unique AS $method)
{
    $relation = $model->$method();
    if(is_a($relation, 'Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation'))
    {
        //... this is a relation, do something with it
    }
}
```

Needless to say, this is very dangerous. Is there a way to do this kind of inspection in a different, more secure way?

Answer (score 0):

You could add PHPDoc comments to your relationship methods and then use the PHP [reflection API](http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php) to extract those from the source.